# GDB shows lines multiple times while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am debugging the simple executable, which has one dll attach to it.
While I am doing the "step up" option of gdb, I am proceeding further line by line, without getting inside function, but sometimes even though there is no loop neither any goto statement, I am seeing the earlier statement is getting executed again, while doing "step up".

I am putting the middle output of the debugging session below, can anyone tell what could be the problem for this?

```
19      file = getenv("DSINSTALL");
(gdb) n
20      file += "/test/rewriteshims.txt";
(gdb) n
21      FILE* fp = fopen(file.str(), "r");
(gdb) 
22      if (!fp) {
(gdb) 
21      FILE* fp = fopen(file.str(), "r");
(gdb) 
22      if (!fp) {
(gdb) 
55          if (strcmp(type, "func") == 0) {
(gdb)
```

As you can see, **the line 21,22 is getting executed again.**
This has happened over other places as well.

Is this related to the way I compile or what? Kindly suggest, this is making it difficult to run through code flow properly.

Code snippet is as below:

```
file = getenv("DSINSTALL");
file += "/test/xyz.txt";
FILE* fp = fopen(file.str(), "r");
if (!fp) {
    perror(file.str());
    return false;
}
char buf[200];
bool err = false;
int line = 0;
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
    line++;
    char* nl = strchr(buf, '\n');
    if (nl) {
        *nl = '\0';
    }....
```

Also, the file is opened properly

Comment: Did you compile in optimized mode? That can explain things.

Comment: What is the type of `file`?

Comment: I changed the tag to [c++] since there's no C type that would allow all the uses of variable `file`, so its type seems to be a C++ class. And this could be relevant, because I suspect a temporary object is involved in the answer.

Comment: @aschepler,  its .cc file

Comment: I mean the variable called `file` - how is it declared?

Comment: can you show the code? I mean I do believe you when you say there is no `goto` or loop, but seeing the code is always better

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, yes, it was optimized one, but i changed it. I am running the below code to compile the executable, still facing the issue:

"g++ -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -O0 -g3 -Wl,-z,noexecstack -O0 -Wl,-z,noexecstack -o rewrite-test . ........"

Comment: `getenv` returns a NULL pointer if the environment variable cannot be found, no?  If so, is the return value `NULL`?  If it is, this code will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: OK, so I'm not surprised then. binary code attached to instructions can be interleaved.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, sorry for this but I am not very clear on this. I mean even if the code is optimized, on statement should run only once right? I am putting the snippet of code in question for clarification.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie We can't know that without knowing what the `file` object does with those expressions. Maybe its `operator=` or `operator+=` include null checks. (Note it's not a `std::string`, since that doesn't have a `str` member.)

Comment: the question is not at all about what each statement is doing, I wanted to know that why the code is not running sequentially and what two times. @MatthieuBrucher answered it i feel.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, can you please tell me, how shall i avoid this so that sequential code follows. It will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at non optimized simple case: https://godbolt.org/z/BG4slZ the code gets interleaved and could explain the gdb behavior.

Comment: Sure, the general answer is that compilers are allowed to rearrange operations as long as all the visible results stay the same, and they often do when optimizations are enabled, resulting in non-sequential debug associations between the machine opcodes and source statements. An explanation using this specific example could go into more detail, if we knew more about what these statements are doing.

Comment: @aschepler OP is only interested in one, the rest is just noise.

Comment: And no, no way to enforce sequential code. PErhaps also update gdb?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher. do you mean I will not be able to see the sequential code flow as we see normally, even though i have disabled optimization.
Also do you mean, that I should update the GDB?

Comment: Perhaps later versions of gdb handle this better, not sure which version you are using.

Comment: Note nothing's actually getting executed twice. It's more like the program does a piece of one statement, then a piece of a second statement which doesn't depend on the first statement being completed, then finishes off something related to the second statement. The program is correct; it's just that debugging gets a bit more confusing.

Comment: @Ghansham "...even though I have disabled optimization" -- there is a high chance you actually *didn't* -- did you rebuild *every* source file with the new flags?

Comment: @employed russian, if we compile only files without optimization but not the library attached to it, then would the debugger work properly when skimming through atleast those files line by line.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, as you mentioned, the object files which was used to create executable were not being compiled with optimization disabled. Those were created by some other make file. I added -g3 -o0 flag, and thus is it working as expected.